# Laravel 10 docker volume permission issue

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-volume

I am running Laravel 10 in docker with volume on AMI Linux 2 server.

Everything is working fine.
However, when I am making syntax error in PHP, the Laravel cannot display the formatted error page.
(Note : I am using default error page. I am not rendering on custom error page)
When I inspect the page, I can see the error.
The error just can't display on the page.
My error page is missing the following
`<div id="app"> . . .</div>`
That is why error cannot be rendered.

Please help me what am I missing here.

I also matched container user and host machine user as follow
`RUN addgroup -g ${GID} --system laravel RUN adduser -G laravel --system -D -s /bin/sh -u ${UID} laravel`

I even gave 777 permission to "storage" and "bootstrap" folder and still not working.